# Angular 2: Conditional Output Property Binding

Tags: angular

Is it possible to conditionally bind to an output property?  Something like this: `<my-Component (myOutputProp)="funcThatReturnsTrueOrFalse()? func1() : func2()"></my-component>`

I've tried the above example, as well as `<my-Component (myOutputProp)="funcThatReturnsFunc1OrFunc2()></my-component>`.

I've looked around and come to the realization that you can't dynamically change bindings after the fact, can't access `EventListeners` from `nativeElement`, and seen some indications that you could do this with regular event bindings, although I couldn't get those to work either.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

My output property is defined like this:

`@Output() myOutputProp: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`

**UPDATE 2**

For reasons beyond my control, I can't just fire one event and branch within that based on true/false.  Primarily because in one situation, a `false` value from my ternary expression evaluation will not bind anything to the output property, and I need to be able to detect that within my child component (via `myOutputProp.observers.length`)

Comment: Why don't you just use an event emitter or similar?

Comment: Why not a separate function or property that returns the value of func1 or func2 based on the value of funcThatReturnsTrueOrFalse?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Output Property *is* an EventEmitter.  Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?  I'll update the question.

Comment: @ACOMIT001: see update, output property is an EventEmitter.  What I need to do is dynamically change the event that gets fired based on true/false.  (And, no, I can't just fire one event and branch within that based on true/false.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `EventEmitter` to *emit* based on your boolean value. Just push the appropriate value via the `emit(...)` method.

Here's a simple example including two components. One component is a button, which emits a String value that changes when you click the button. The other component is consuming that event and displaying it. You can find a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4natth

Here's the first component, which is a simple button. Note that clicking the button sets a boolean flag. This flag then determines which string is emitted by the event emitter.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-example',
  template: '<button mat-raised-button (click)="doThings()">Click me!</button>'
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  @Output()
  status: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  flag = false;

  doThings() {
    this.flag = !this.flag; // toggle the boolean flag
    this.status.emit(this.getValue()); // push the value
  }

  private getValue() {
    if(this.flag) {
      return "Truthy!";
    }
    return "Falsy!";
  }
}
```

The second component is consuming and the values being emitted from `(status)`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-container',
  template: '<my-example (status)="updateStatus($event)">loading...</my-example><p>Current status: {{status}}</p>'
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  status: string = "Not set yet - click the button!";

  updateStatus(value: string) {
    this.status = value;
  }
}
```

Whenever you click the button, the `EventEmitter.emit(...)` method is called, pushing the appropriate value. On the other end, the event is consumed using `(status)="updateStatus($event)"`, where in this case `$event` is of type string because I've declared the EventEmitter to be emitting a string. I could easily have also been emitting a boolean value and have the `updateStatus` method instead do different things based on the emitted value.

---

So, say for example you have this in your Component:

```
@Output()
myOutputProp: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
```

You could then do something like this:

```
<my-Component (myOutputProp)="someFunc($event)"></my-component>
```

And define your `someFunc` like this:

```
someFunc(emittedValue: boolean) {
  emittedValue ? func1() : func2();
}
```

---

Or, let's say you need the output of your event emitter to be some sort of value that you need preserved rather than a boolean. You could still declare your component the same:

```
<my-Component (myOutputProp)="someFunc($event)"></my-component>
```

And define your `someFunc` like this:

```
someFunc(emittedValue: any) { 
  funcThatReturnsTrueOrFalse() ? func1(emittedValue) : func2(emittedValue);
}
```

So while you can't *directly* bind the ternary to the event emitter, you can instead bind something static which turns around and invokes the ternary itself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I had put in a comment above about not being able to take this route and have now edited my question to include it and expanded upon it a bit.  Sorry I didn't make that clearer before you typed all of that out.  :-(